# Error while configuring salesforce with eclipse Force.com IDE

Tags: community

While trying to configure eclipse neon 3.0, i am getting the bellow error message. Please help to resolve.
[image: Eclipse Error]

Unable to fetch and save Force.com components to project:
Premature EOF
Abort or Continue Force.com project creation?

Comment: Hi Chandra, did any of the below answers help you? if so, please consider accepting one. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install lower version of Force IDE plugin...I also faced the same issue and tried with lower version of Force IDE and it worked for me.
once check the jdk in install on your system or not.If there are multiple versions jdk installed make sure that you are using supported version.

follow this steps:--

Go to Eclipse->Preferences. IN the preference page use the quick find to search for "Java", then scroll the left panel to "Installed JRE's"

On the right, click "Search" and hopefully, eclipse will find your new JDK / JRE installation. Check the new one as the default, and restart eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the eclipse.ini file and, add the following line to the eclipse.ini file, near the top:

-clean

Thank you
Amol Salve
Salesforce Developer